# Problems with arithenco(seq, counts) function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, encoding

I have individual bits in an array and I am passing them into the arithenco(seq, counts) function.

```
    seq = int8(seq);
    p1 = 100*(sum(seq)/length(seq));
    counts = [p1 1];
    code = arithenco(seq, counts);
```

It keeps failing at the error checking:

```
    % Check to make sure that finite positive integer values (non-complex) are 
    % entered for SEQ
    if ~all(seq > 0) || ~all(isfinite(seq)) || ~isequal(seq, round(seq)) || ...
        ~isreal(seq)
        error(message('comm:arithenco:InvalidSymbolSequenceParameter1'));
    return;    
end
```

I was originally passing in a double array, so i changed it with `seq = uint8(seq);` and 
`seq = int8(seq)` but I am still getting this error!

I'm new to Matlab and I'm sure this is an easy fix, but whatever I try just does not fix it.

The arithenco() documentation states:

```
code = arithenco(seq,counts) generates the binary arithmetic code corresponding to the sequence of symbols specified in the vector seq. The vector counts represents the source's statistics by listing the number of times each symbol of the source's alphabet occurs in a test data set.

This example illustrates the compression that arithmetic coding can accomplish in some situations. A source has a two-symbol alphabet and produces a test data set in which 99% of the symbols are 1s. Encoding 1000 symbols from this source produces a code vector having many fewer than 1000 elements. The actual number of elements in code varies, depending on the particular random sequence contained in seq.

counts = [99 1]; % A one occurs 99% of the time.
len = 1000;
seq = randsrc(1,len,[1 2; .99 .01]); % Random sequence
code = arithenco(seq,counts);
s = size(code) % length of code is only 8.3% of length of seq.
The output is

s = 1    83
```

Comment: It specifically fails at `if ~all(seq > 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the bits in your sequence, or with the way you generate the counts array. The following works fine:

```
len = 1000;
seq = randsrc(1,len,[1 2; .99 .01]);
counts = [99 1];
code = arithenco(seq, counts);
```

I think your problem is probably here:

```
p1 = 100*(sum(seq)/length(seq));
```

Your p1 must be an integer.

If you believe your sequence to be correct, you can try something like the following:

```
p1 = floor(100*(sum(seq)/length(seq)));
```

Comment: Using floor will floor the p1, to 44 rather than 44.4444, it was a good idea but the error still exists.

`Error using arithenco>errorchk (line 175)
The symbol sequence parameter must be a vector of positive finite integers.`

does this mean I cannot have 0s? my sequence is a sequence of bits i.e. 1s and 0s?

Comment: That seems to be it! specifically at the part in the validation `if ~all(seq > 0)` how am i supposed to encode binary then? confused!

Comment: I have no idea what you mean when you say you want to "encode binary", but the values in your sequence must be greater than zero and less than the length of your counts array.

Comment: THanks for your help! I just mean encode a sequence of binary digits, for example, [1;0;0;1;1;1;0;0;1]

Comment: I don't think you understand what the purpose of arithenco() is. What do you mean encode a sequence of binary digits? That doesn't mean anything to me. Provide an example of your encoding. Show me the map.

Comment: I am extracting the most significant bit from each pixel in an image, and storing this in a sequence. The next step is to arithmetically code this sequence so it is compressed and I can then return it back to the image (with information added into the spare pixels). Perhaps I need to turn the bits in the sequence into 8-bit characters before passing into arithenco()?

Comment: I still don't understand. You're going to take the compressed (encoded?) pixel information and return it back to the image. What does it mean to return the compressed information back to the image? You could try turning the bits in the sequence into characters. Again, the values that are allowed in your sequence fall in the range of 1 to length(counts).